# HTML Attributes in Flow?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

What is the equivalent of the TypeScript expression in Flow?

```
React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>
```

For instance, I would like to define a type that inherits the properties of a `div` element.

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is:

```js
type Props = HTMLDivElement & { myOwnProp: string }
```

Comment: The problem here is that `HTMLDivElement` contains the native attributes, like `onclick`. It does not match the react world, where the attribute would be `onClick`.